# Unable to install & access & login mysql after upgrade 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, upgrade, mysql

I upgraded from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, and now my mysql is not working. I remember there was some notice was mentioned while upgrading from mysql 5.7 to mysql 8.0 in the process; which I cannot remember correctly.

Now, I cannot install mysql. This is what I get :

```
maan@maan-Inspiron-5537:~$ sudo apt install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version (8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 

Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server:
2021-02-08T08:39:12.431863Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000077] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Error while setting value 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_
FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' to 'sql_mode'.
2021-02-08T08:39:12.493831Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
Please take a look at https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/FAQ for tips on fixing common upgrade issues.
Once the problem is resolved, run apt-get --fix-broken install to retry.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
maan@maan-Inspiron-5537:~$
```

I do not want to delete the existing databases.

Is there a way out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER` mode setting, as [it was completely removed from MySQL 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-nutshell.html#mysql-nutshell-removals). You will need to find where this is defined in your configuration files (either `my.cnf`, `mysql.cnf`, or something similar depending on how you've configured your MySQL installation) and remove it. You can also remove the other modes from being explicitly declared as [the documentation makes clear](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/faqs-sql-modes.html#faq-mysql-what-default-mode):

| A.3.7. | What is the default server SQL mode when MySQL 8.0 is installed? |
| --- | --- |
|  | The default SQL mode in MySQL 8.0 includes these modes: `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`, `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE`, `NO_ZERO_DATE`, `ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO`, and `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`. |

For information about all available modes and default MySQL behavior, see [Section 5.1.11, “Server SQL Modes”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html).

---

Once these mode flags are removed, you should be able to start MySQL. The system will likely complain about the tables being of the wrong version the first time it starts, then the engine will immediately upgrade the 5.7 databases to the newer 8.0 system. If you have any databases that make use of MyISAM, you will want to seriously look at getting them updated to use InnoDB in the near future, as MySQL 8.0 will send messages that the older MyISAM tables are being deprecated in the future.

Hope this gives you a working database installation again